Sync contributions between public GitHub repo and its private GitLab mirror
Background
I have a public repo on GitHub that stores the latest updates of my project.
┌───────────────┐        ┌───────────────┐           ┌────────────────┐
│               │        │               │           │                │
│    GitHub     │ Public │    GitHub     │  Private  │    GitLab      │
│               │ contrib│               │  contrib  │                │
│  Public fork  ◄────────►  Public repo  │x─────────x│ Private mirror │
│               │ Create │               │  Cannot   │                │
│  Downstream   │   PR   │   Upstream    │ create PR │   Downstream   │
│               │        │               │ (push/pull│                │
└───────────────┘        └───────────────┘  via local└────────────────┘
                                            machine)                   

The contributions are done publicly and privately:

Public contributions are trivial - just create a PR on GitHub.
Private contributions are needed for some changes whose review or work-in-progress details shouldn't be revealed. For such changes, I set up a private mirror on GitLab. I periodically sync the GitLab mirror with the public repo and work on MRs there.

As I said, I have a GitLab mirror. It means that I do not make any changes to the main branch there, I only pull the changes from upstream. I know that there are things like bidirectional mirror which can probably be used in my case but is usually advised against doing for CAP theorem as so on.
As a result, the workflow for private contributions (pushing the changes from the private mirror on GitLab to the public repo on GitHub) is as follows:

In the private mirror on GitLab:

a. Sync the main branch with upstream
b. Create a new branch, make changes, and create an MR
c. Have the changes in the MR reviewed and approved


Once the work on the MR is finished, I do the following:

a. Close the MR on GitLab
b. Pull the branch with changes on my local machine
c. Push the branch upstream to my public repo on GitHub via the local machine
d. Create and merge the PR on my public repo on GitHub



My questions
There are the following things that I don't like about my workflow:

The MRs on GitLab are closed. I cannot merge them, because the GitLab repo is a mirror (I explained the reasons earlier). Can MRs be dealt with in a better or cleaner way?
The step 2c ("Push the branch upstream to my public repo on GitHub via the local machine") is done manually. Can and should I automate this process? If yes, how can I do it?



You can create two labels merged and abandoned to mark whether the MR was closed and merged on GitHub, or abandoned, respectively.

I'm not sure what you mean. If you frequently need to do 2b and 2c together, you can write a script that perform these two steps: (assuming  remotegitlab points to GitLab and remote github points to GitHub)


#!/bin/bash

git pull gitlab "$@" && git push github "$@"

The script takes a branch name as its command line argument.

Thank you for the answer!

Good point about using labels. Maybe I can go with them.
Can you please recommend a good way to trigger the script execution?


@f-hollow You can use gitlab and github APIs to complete steps 2a-d, but I don't know if you want to do them. You would need to set up a scheduled pipeline on gitlab, which retrieves recently closed MRs and checks their labels, and them pushes to github and opens a PR. You also need to establish the authorization of the push. Depending how many people are using this workflow, I don't know if it's worth the effort.

Great, this is exactly what I needed! I would gladly accept the answer, but I do not have enough points on StackOverflow. Once I do, I will upvote it. Sorry for that!

One interesting detail. After finishing the work on my MR on GitLab, I kept it open. Then I went through the syncing process with the GitHub repo (2b - 2d). After that, as soon as I synced the main branch on GitLab with upstream (1a), my MR (previously merged on GitHub during 2d) automatically changed the status to "merged". That unexpectedly resolved my concerns about clean ways of dealing with GitLab MRs!
